# why GPIO SPI undefined on efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

I have tried to define SPI and its GPIO inside a function initUSART1() but it said as shown bellow in the photo,that its not defined although i added gpio and usart libraries as shown in the code bellow.
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.

[image]

```
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_adc.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#define adcFreq   16000000

volatile uint32_t sample;
volatile uint32_t millivolts;

/////////////////////start SPI
void initUSART1 (void)
{
    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART1, true);

    // Configure GPIO mode
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 8, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_CLK is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 9, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_CS is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 6, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_TX (MOSI) is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 7, gpioModeInput, 1);    // US1_RX (MISO) is input
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortF, 7, gpioModeInput, 1);    // delay gpio

    // Start with default config, then modify as necessary
    USART_InitSync_TypeDef config = USART_INITSYNC_DEFAULT;
    config.master       = true;            // master mode
    config.baudrate     = 1000000;         // CLK freq is 1 MHz
    config.autoCsEnable = true;            // CS pin controlled by hardware, not firmware
    config.clockMode    = usartClockMode0; // clock idle low, sample on rising/first edge
    config.autoCsEnable = true;            // CS pin controlled by  firmware
    config.msbf         = true;            // send MSB first
    config.enable       = usartDisable;    // Make sure to keep USART disabled until it's all set up
    USART_InitSync(USART1, &config);

    // Set USART pin locations
    USART1->ROUTELOC0 = (USART_ROUTELOC0_CLKLOC_LOC11) | // US1_CLK       on location 11 = PC8 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 8
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_CSLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_CS        on location 11 = PC9 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 10
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_TXLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_TX (MOSI) on location 11 = PC6 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 4
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_RXLOC_LOC11);   // US1_RX (MISO) on location 11 = PC7 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 6

    // Enable USART pins
    USART1->ROUTEPEN = USART_ROUTEPEN_CLKPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_CSPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN;



    // Enable USART1
    USART_Enable(USART1, usartEnable);


     // Enable oscillator to GPIO and USART0 modules


}//end usart init

//////////////////////end SPI


/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief  Initialize ADC function
 *****************************************************************************/
void initADC (void)
{
  // Enable ADC0 clock
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_ADC0, true);

  // Declare init structs
  ADC_Init_TypeDef init = ADC_INIT_DEFAULT;
  ADC_InitSingle_TypeDef initSingle = ADC_INITSINGLE_DEFAULT;

  // Modify init structs and initialize
  init.prescale = ADC_PrescaleCalc(adcFreq, 0); // Init to max ADC clock for Series 1
  init.timebase = ADC_TimebaseCalc(0);

  initSingle.diff       = false;        // single ended
  initSingle.reference  = adcRef5V;    // internal 5V reference
  initSingle.resolution = adcRes12Bit;  // 12-bit resolution
  initSingle.acqTime    = adcAcqTime4;  // set acquisition time to meet minimum requirements

  // Select ADC input. See README for corresponding EXP header pin.
  initSingle.posSel = adcPosSelAPORT4XCH11;

  ADC_Init(ADC0, &init);
  ADC_InitSingle(ADC0, &initSingle);

  // Enable ADC Single Conversion Complete interrupt
  ADC_IntEnable(ADC0, ADC_IEN_SINGLE);

  // Enable ADC interrupts
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(ADC0_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC0_IRQn);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief  ADC Handler
 *****************************************************************************/
void ADC0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Get ADC result
  sample = ADC_DataSingleGet(ADC0);

  // Calculate input voltage in mV
  millivolts = (sample * 2500) / 4096;

  // Start next ADC conversion
  ADC_Start(ADC0, adcStartSingle);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief  Main function
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  CHIP_Init();

  initADC();
  initUSART1();

  // Start first conversion
  ADC_Start(ADC0, adcStartSingle);

  // Infinite loop
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: It tells you that those functions are not declared anywhere. You call them, but there is no such function in the entire your project, so ...

Comment: yeah, the right question here would be "why *should* it be defined?".

Comment: Hello Marcus i Have defined the clock for USART and the em libraried for it.What am i missing? Thanks.

Comment: What's inside the "em_gpio.h" ?

Comment: Thank you very much :-)